# Powershell: where depending on exit code from command without temp variable

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I'm trying to limit a pipeline output to those elements where a certain command's exit code is 0.

```
$myData | where { $temp = sqlcmd -i Checker.sql -v DATA=$_; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 }
```

Checker.sql raises an error if the data doesn't pass the check.

Is there a way to tell PowerShell to ignore the output of sqlcmd without putting it into a temp variable?  If I don't include the `$temp =`, I just get back my original data set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe the output to `Out-Null`:

```
$myData | where { sqlcmd -i Checker.sql -v DATA=$_ | Out-Null; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 }
```